# How to send mail with multiple attachments?

Tags: sendmail, mailx

I need to read list of files from another file and attach them together and send mail.

e.g. filenames.txt has:

```
/path/file1
/path/file2
/path/file3
/path/file4
```

Command or script should read from filenames.txt and attach file1,file2,file3 and file4 in email and send.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use `mutt` to send emails with attachments from scripts:

```bash
$ cat mail.txt | \
    mutt -s 'My Subject' \
      -a /path/file1 /path/file2 /path/file3 /path/file4 \
      -- email@example.com
```

You need to use `--` to separate between the attached files and the destination address.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use `mutt` to read and send mails.
Assuming that your file `filenames.txt` is:

```
/path/to/file1
/path/to/file2
```

I would write:

```
mutt -s "Subject" -a $(<filenames.txt) -- dest@example.com < mailbody.txt
```