# 18.04.1-Ubuntu: Mail command unable to set mail body with attachment

Tags: ubuntu, mail-command

I am trying to use `mail` command to send 2 attachments. The issue which i am facing is unable to send attachment and mail body content. tried following command

```
echo "Hello World" | mail -s 'Test Email' -A test.csv -aFrom:no-reply@test.com abcd@test.com
```

```
cat README.txt | mail -s 'Test Email' -A test.csv -aFrom:no-reply@test.com abcd@test.com
```

```
mail -s 'Test Email' -A test.csv -aFrom:no-reply@test.com abcd@test.com < README.txt
```

Whereas I send mail body alone then mail is received with body

```
mail -s 'Test Email' -aFrom:no-reply@test.com abcd@test.com  < README.txt
```

How to send both attachment and mail body (`README.txt` in mail body and `test.csv` in attachment)?

Comment: You mean you want send `README.txt` and `test.csv`, [both](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/329050/72456), in attachment?

Comment: README.txt is mail body and test.csv in attachment

Comment: `-a` is used to send attachments not `-A`

Comment: In man mail it shows  -A, --attach=FILE, -a, --append=HEADER: VALUE append given header to the message being sent

Comment: Done. its 18.04.1-Ubuntu

Comment: one silly question, but is `test.csv` exist there in current directory you are executing the command?

Comment: Yes the file exists in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a [bug in the version of `mailutils`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mailutils/+bug/1911894). While searching I came across the [mailing list](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=918806#22) where a solution was offered:

> you can use the `--mime` option as a workaround:
>
> ```
> echo "body text" | /usr/bin/mail --mime -s "some subject" -A "somefile.csv" my@email.com
> ```

This adds the body text as an attachment, but it's better than nothing!